# Regular expression for invalid characters in XML

Tags: regex, xml

I am trying to figure out a way where I can find all the invalid characters in an XML. 
According to [W3 recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets) these are the valid characters in an XML:

```
#x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

Converting it to decimal:

```
9
10
13
32-55295
57344-65533
65536-1114111
```

are the valid xml characters.

I am trying to search in notepad++ using the appropriate regular expression for the invalid characters.

A snippet from my XML:

```
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="isContendFeed">fal &#11; se</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="pageNoFollow">fal &#3; se</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="pageNoIndex">fal &#13; se</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="rrRecommendable">false</custom-attribute>
```

From the above example I want that my regular expression finds `&#11;` and  `&#3;` for me because these are not allowed in an XML.

I am not able to construct the regular expression for this.

The regular expression I made for the numeric ranges:

```
32-55295 : (3[2-9]|[4-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2,3}|[1-4][0-9]{4}|5[0-4][0-9]{3}|55[01][0-9]{2}|552[0-8][0-9]|5529[0-5])
57344-65533 : (5734[4-9]|573[5-9][0-9]|57[4-9][0-9]{2}|5[89][0-9]{3}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-3])
65536-1114111 : (6(5(5(3[6-9]|[4-9][0-9])|[6-9][0-9]{2})|[6-9][0-9]{3})|[7-9][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{5}|1(0[0-9]{5}|1(0[0-9]{4}|1([0-3][0-9]{3}|4(0[0-9]{2}|1(0[0-9]|1[01])))))))
```

These regular expression are working if used separately but I am not able to make the complete regex.

Is there any other way other than the regular expression by which I can find the invalid characters? If not, please help me in constructing the regular expression which can find invalid characters present in my XML.

Comment: you could just launch a validating tool like `xmllint` on it

Comment: I found a notepad++ plugin [XMLTools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XML%20Tools/Xml%20Tools%202.4.6%20Unicode/) which served the purpose. The only problem is it gives the invalid characters one my one, not all in one go.

Comment: do you mean that invalid characters are numbers  `1-8`
`11,12` `14-31` `55296-57343` `65534,65535`
`and any number greater than 1114111`

Comment: @NaderHisham No. Invalid characters are characters having decimal code among the numbers you mentioned. Look at the XML in the question. [See this](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets). I have only converted these from hex to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

first, the literal text `&#3;` is allowed in xml - not allowed (if the list is correct) is the character with the ascii-code 3. Hope I got that right.

Second. Most regular expression flavors allow to search for characters that can be defined with `\x00` (two hex digits) and `\u0000` (4 hex digits).
Some flavors allow something like `\x{...}` - but it differs from flavor to flavor...

We start with

`[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD]`

`[^]` defines a negated set of characters and character ranges (and more). Simply fill it with all the allowed characters and ranges.

If your flavor understands `\x{}`, it's easy to extend.

```
[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}]
```

Otherwise you have to search for the [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF) characters by character...

`\x{10000}` is the same as `\uD800\uDC00`

`\x{10FFFF}` is the same as `\uDBFF\uDFFF`

That could not be done in a single set. No fun ;) It's something like the negated version of

```
[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|
[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|
(?:[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF]
```

(from https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode#matching-code-points)